# How would I add a gap between each grid section using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have looked through the Bootstrap info online as well as a few answers on here but i still cant find a way to put a gap between each of the sections in a grid. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#214B68;">
     <div class="div-left"><h2>Title1</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
    </div>
```

Structure

[image: Grid Structure]

Answer (score 0):

You can us the margin (`m`) and padding (`p`) classes that are included in bootstrap e.g.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 m-3" style="background-color:#214B68;">
    <div class="div-left m-3"><h2>Title1</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
</div>
```

You can mix `m` and `p` with `r` `t` `b` `l` (right, top, bottom, left) to get the spacing you need. For example `mr-3` (margin-right: 3em;)

There is more information here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

EDIT TO FIX GRID STRUCTURE.

You seem to want separation of rows but only some of your sections have defined rows. If you ensure each section is within a row class then you can add CSS as follows:

```
.row {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Working code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

  <style>

.row {margin-bottom: 3em;}


  i {
    color: white;
    font-size: 150px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  h2 {
    color: white;
  }

  h3 {
    color: white;
  }

  .col-sm-6, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-12 {
  min-height: 200px;
  }

  .btn-primary {
    background-color: white;
    color:#214B68;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }



  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">   
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#214B68;">
    <div class="div-left"><h2>Title1</h2>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#214B68;">
        <div class="div-left m-3"><h2>Office Removals</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 m-3" style="background-color:#1BB1A2;">
        <div class="div-left m-3"><h2>House Clearances</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 m-3" style="background-color:#1BB1A2;">
        <div class="div-left m-3"><h2>Office Clearances</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#1BB1A2;">
        <div class="div-left"><h2>Garage Clearances</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#EA5380;">
        <div class="div-left"><h2>Collection and Delivery</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:#658091;">
            <div class="div-left"><h3>Pricing For All Services</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
            </div>
            <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:#658091;">
            <div class="div-left"><h3>Free Quote</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
            </div>
            <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:#658091;">
            <div class="div-left"><h3>Tips and Guides For Moving House</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>  
            </div>
            <div class="div-right"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still seem to be having problems, i've just put the code into here and it doesnt seem to work, maybe i've got something blocking it working in the css? I've tried to define "m-3" as well but it just moves the columns underneath - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEL0ZJZ5NW1W

Comment: please see the edit. The issue is due to the way you are structuring your html. Ensure for each section you have <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">SECTION HTML HERE</div></div>

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to have a row for each section even if i was a 2, 2, 2, 3 column structure for each row? Still having problems with the gap between the columns. Ive added a diagram to my original post.

Comment: Check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/2suov8a7. This is how you should structure your grid. Notice I have used the class mx-2 on the columns which gives you a margin on the left and right of the element.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. One last thing, if I wanted to make it responsive on small devices to display each section on top of each other, how would i do this? So just 1 column and 9 rows. thanks

Comment: You can use breakpoints using the col-sm-6 (for example) classes. Please read this and play around until you find an approach that works https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks, i've read this but i think i am wrestling with the theme the site is using and therefore need to use !important for a lot of things which i was not aware of before. Again thanks so much for your help, I am hopefully getting there with it all